# Python list generator not working as intended

Tags: python, list, printing

First of all, I'm making a game in which the map is a list of lists:

```
P1.Cmap = [
      ['0,'0',0'],
      ['0,'0',0'],
      ['0,'0',0'],
]
```

and I have a function to print it:

```
def render(): #render the map to player
    P1.Cmap[P1.y][P1.x] = P1.char
    j = 40 - len(P1.Cmap)
    p = int(j/2)
    l = len(P1.Cmap[0])
    print('\n' * p)
    print('-' * l)
    for r in P1.Cmap:
        print(''.join(r))
    print('\n' * p)
```

where P1 is the player object and char is the character to represent it (X)

and I also made a function to generate a map with the given parameters:

```
def newMap():
    Nmn = input('What is the name of the map? ')
    NmSx = input('What is the size you want?(X) ')
    NmSy = input('What is the size you want?(Y) ')
    Row = []
    Map = []
    for r in range(int(NmSx)):
        Row.append('0')
    for c in range(int(NmSy)):
        Map.append(Row)
    P1.Cmap = Map
    print(P1.Cmap)
```

but when I set the player X and Y to be P1.x = 1, P1.y = 0 and I use the function to generate the map, it actually prints:

```
0X0
0X0
0X0
```

instead of what it "should" (When I make the map like the first code block above):

```
0X0
000
000
```

with that I thought that the problem is not in the render() but it is in the newMap(), but I can't seem to find it, any ideas?

Comment: Your list is not in Python syntax. There are too few or to many quotation marks and commas missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `P1.Cmap` in the following way:

```
Row = []
Map = []
for r in range(int(NmSx)):
    Row.append('0')
for c in range(int(NmSy)):
    Map.append(Row)
P1.Cmap = Map
```

However, this makes `Map` equal to `[Row, Row, Row]`, that is, `Row` is *always referencing the same list* you created above with `Row = []`, therefore any time you modify `Row` the changes will be reflected in `Map` in all three "rows", since each "row" is `Row`!.

Instead, try something like :

```
X = int(NmSx)
Y = int(NmSy)
Map = [['0' for _ in range(X)] for _ in range(Y)]
```